# Truncate year, group by year and count another column in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to use the following sql code to get Year information from MyDate and count unique CustomerId but get error.

```
SELECT YEAR(MyDate) AS MyYear, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId) AS MyCustomerCount

FROM MyTable

GROUP BY MyYear
```

However the following code works.

```
SELECT YEAR(MyDate), COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId)

FROM MyTable

GROUP BY YEAR(MyDate)
```

Why can't alias be used in this scenario?

Comment: `...but get error` ... please add the entire error message to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because this is how it was defined in SQL standard.

**Syntax rules**

*Group by clause is defined as:*

[image]

However *Order by clause is defined as bellow*

[image]

So here you can see alias exists after order by clause then we can use it normally but not after group by clause.